# Why pymysql not insert record into table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I am pretty new in python developing. I have a long python script what "clone" a database and add additional stored functions and procedures. Clone means copy only the schema of DB.These steps work fine.

My question is about *pymysql* insert exection:
I have to copy some table contents into the new DB. I don't get any sql error. If I debug or print the created *INSERT INTO* command is correct (I've tested it in an sql editor/handler). The insert execution is correct becuse the result contain the exact row number...but all rows are missing from destination table in dest.DB...
(Ofcourse DB_* variables have been definied!)

```
import pymysql

liveDbConn = pymysql.connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD, LIVE_DB_NAME)
testDbConn = pymysql.connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD, TEST_DB_NAME)

tablesForCopy = ['role', 'permission']
for table in tablesForCopy:
    with liveDbConn.cursor() as liveCursor:
        # Get name of columns
        liveCursor.execute("DESCRIBE `%s`;" % (table))
        columns = '';
        for column in liveCursor.fetchall():
            columns += '`' + column[0] + '`,'
        columns = columns.strip(',')
        
        # Get and convert values
        values = ''
        liveCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `%s`;" % (table))
        for result in liveCursor.fetchall():
            data = []
            for item in result:
                if type(item)==type(None):
                    data.append('NULL')
                elif type(item)==type('str'):
                    data.append("'"+item+"'")
                elif type(item)==type(datetime.datetime.now()):
                    data.append("'"+str(item)+"'")
                else:  # for numeric values
                    data.append(str(item))
            v = '(' + ', '.join(data) + ')'
            values += v + ', '
    values = values.strip(', ')
    
    print("### table: %s" % (table))
    testDbCursor = testDbConn.cursor()
    testDbCursor.execute("INSERT INTO `" + TEST_DB_NAME + "`.`" + table + "` (" + columns + ") VALUES " + values + ";")
    print("Result: {}".format(testDbCursor._result.message))
    

liveDbConn.close()
testDbConn.close()
```

Result is:

```
### table: role 
Result: b"'Records: 16  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0"
### table: permission 
Result: b'(Records: 222  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The shown code should fail because you import a `pymsql` but then use `pymysql`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher! That's a typo only here! I've checked my code where import line is correct.
I am going to fix this typo here...

Comment: You don't `commit()` your changes

Comment: The queries are all sorts of bad with string concatenation too. This is vulnerable to SQL Injection in addition to being very difficult to read

Comment: @roganjosh! I've checked many pages how to use pymysql but I didn't find/saw any pages where suggested to us commit(). I've thought it would be necessary but even I didn't find any comment/suggestion to use it...I leave it. 
Now I tried it and it's work!

Would you be to add your suggestion as an answer? I would like to rate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 main issues here:

1. You don't use `conn.commit()` (which would be either be `liveDbConn.commit()` or `testDbConn.commit()` here). Changes to the database will not be reflected without committing those changes. Note that all *changes* need committing but `SELECT`, for example, does not.
2. Your query is open to SQL Injection. This is a serious problem.

Table names cannot be parameterized, so there's not much we can do about that, but you'll want to parameterize your values. I've made multiple corrections to the code in relation to type checking as well as parameterization.

```
for table in tablesForCopy:
    with liveDbConn.cursor() as liveCursor:        
        liveCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `%s`;" % (table))
        name_of_columns = [item[0] for item in liveCursor.description]
        insert_list = []
        for result in liveCursor.fetchall():
            data = []
            for item in result:
                if item is None: # test identity against the None singleton
                    data.append('NULL')
                elif isinstance(item, str): # Use isinstance to check type
                    data.append(item)
                elif isinstance(item, datetime.datetime):
                    data.append(item.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                else:  # for numeric values
                    data.append(str(item))
            insert_list.append(data)

    testDbCursor = testDbConn.cursor()
    placeholders = ', '.join(['`%s`' for item in insert_list[0]])
    testDbCursor.executemany("INSERT INTO `{}.{}` ({}) VALUES ({})".format(
                                                                TEST_DB_NAME, 
                                                                table, 
                                                                name_of_columns, 
                                                                placeholders),
                             insert_list)
    testDbConn.commit()
```

---

From [this github thread](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/491), I notice that `executemany` does not work as expected in `psycopg2`; it instead sends each entry as a single query. You'll need to use [`execute_batch`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_batch):

```
from psycopg2.extras import execute_batch

execute_batch(testDbCursor,
              "INSERT INTO `{}.{}` ({}) VALUES ({})".format(TEST_DB_NAME, 
                                                            table, 
                                                            name_of_columns, 
                                                            placeholders),
              insert_list)
testDbConn.commit()
```

Comment: @aBanhidy please see my edit. I overlooked `executemany` not working as I expected in `psycopg2` vs. other SQL libraries

Answer (score 1):

How to insert data into table using python pymsql 
Find my solution below

```
import pymysql
import datetime

# Create a connection object
dbServerName    = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8889
dbUser          = "root"
dbPassword      = ""
dbName          = "blog_flask"
# charSet         = "utf8mb4"

conn   = pymysql.connect(host=dbServerName, user=dbUser, password=dbPassword,db=dbName, port= port)
try:
    # Create a cursor object
    cursor           = conn.cursor()

    # Insert rows into the MySQL Table 
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    my_datetime = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO posts (post_id, post_title, post_content, \
    filename,post_time) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',(5,'title2','description2','filename2',my_datetime))
    conn.commit()

except Exception as e:
    print("Exeception occured:{}".format(e))

finally:
    conn.close()
```